# SQL Server: Using columns with identical names

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm writing a migration script to move data from one data model to another in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. The problem I'm running into is that, in the source database, some tables have foreign key columns that I need to compare. A snippet of code:

```
INSERT INTO TargetDB.dbo.Encounter(EncounterID, PATID, DRG)
Select
visit_occurrence_id,
person_id,
(Select
    Case when ((Select top 1 observation_concept_id from SourceDB.dbo.Observation where visit_occurrence_id = visit_occurrence_id) = 3040464)
    Then (Select top 1 value_as_string from SourceDB.dbo.Observation where visit_occurrence_id = visit_occurrence_id)
    Else NULL End
)
from SourceDB.dbo.Visit_occurrence
```

As you can see, I need to compare visit_occurrence_id in SourceDB.dbo.Observation to visit_occurrence_id in SourceDB.dbo.Visit_occurrence. As it is, it's just returning values from the first row in SourceDB.dbo.Observation, since visit_occurrence_id will always equal itself.

What's the proper way to do this? Can I assign the first visit_occurrence_id value to a variable within the query, so it has a distinct name? I'm pretty lost here.

Comment: Just fully-qualify the name: SourceDB.dbo.Observation.visit_occurence

Comment: You can also alias the table: SourceDB.dbo.Observation AS A - then, use A.visit_occurence in your WHERE

Comment: That's the ticket! The first solution worked perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to add a little more detail for you here in an answer.  You can always refer to an object by it's fully-qualified name, but it isn't always necessary:

```
Database.Schema.Table
```

or

```
Database.Schema.Table.Column
```

with sql server, it can even include server for linked-server scenarios.

also true of other objects like views, procedures, functions, etc...  Aliasing of tables and/or columns can be a good strategy for shortening this qualification.

Anytime there is ambiguity, this is necessary.  However, it is a good practice to be fairly explicit, because it can save you future headaches.  As an example, consider this view:

```
CREATE VIEW vwEmployeesWithLocation AS 
SELECT
  E.EmployeeId   -- from employees
  , LastName     -- from employees
  , Status       -- from employees
  , LocationName -- from locations
FROM
  Employees AS E
  INNER JOIN
  EmployeeLocations AS EL ON E.EmloyeeId = EL.EmployeeId
  INNER JOIN
  Locations AS L ON EL.LocationId = L.LocationId
```

Right now, everything is fine because other than EmployeeId, the column names are distinct.  However, someone might add a Status column to the Locations table in the future and break this view.  So, it would be better to explicitly include the table prefix for all columns in the select.

In your case, your query is cross database, so again, be explicit about the database in all parts of your query.

Answer (score 0):

Used snow_FFFFFF's answer in the comments: Just used SourceDB.dbo.Observation.visit_occurence_id.